# Laravel Eloquent ORM - How to get the all the properties of afrom/of a collection in a array?

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

```php
$user_emails = ["email_1@domain.com", "email_2@domain.org"];

$users = Users::whereIn("email", $user_emails);
```

The table for users also has a `phone` column for each user. What's the best way to get a `list/array` of the phone number as an array?

```php
$users->all()->phone(); // Like (which is not correct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck` method to fetch a specific column's values and then use `toArray` on returned `Collection` object to get results as an array.

```php
$phoneNumbers = Users::whereIn("email", $user_emails)->pluck('phone')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `get()` like :

```
$users = Users::whereIn("email", $user_emails)->get(['phone'])->toArray();
```

Or also `pluck()` like :

```
$users = Users::whereIn("email", $user_emails)->pluck('phone')->all();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second option is the better way

Answer (score 1):

You can get all column data with `get()`

#### Example:

```
$user = $user::where('email', $user_emails)->get();
```

You can get the list with `foreach` loop method.

Comment: _get a list/array of the phone number as an array_ that will return a collection of users, not what the OP serching for..

Comment: Since $user_emails is an array this will not work. That's why I have used `::whereIn`. I could have done a for loop and appended the phone number for each user in an array but that wouldn't be efficient because I would have to make a single query for each user.